# How to write the test for a Model that uses firestore documentsnapshot

Tags: flutter, unit-testing, dart, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-test

Currently I am following TDD but now I am stuck in a point where I want to test a UserModel class that emits a UserEntity based on a documentsnapshot. This is the code I want to test.

```
  factory UserModel.fromSnapsot(DocumentSnapshot snapshot) {
    return UserModel(
      email: snapshot.get('email').data(),
      username: snapshot.get('username').data(),
      uid: snapshot.get('uid').data(),
    );
  }
```

And I wrote a test but it failed by saying

> The method 'get' was called on null. Receiver: null. Tried calling: get("email")

The code that I wrote is

```
  group('fromSnapshot', () {
    when(UserModel.fromSnapsot(mockDocumentSnapshot))
        .thenAnswer((_) => tUserModel);

    final result = UserModel.fromSnapsot(mockDocumentSnapshot);

    expect(result, tUserModel);
  });
```

Any idea of how I can test the above code?

Comment: `mockDocumentSnapshot` is null, it has to be a valid snapshot, not null

Comment: Is there a way to make a custom snapshot with data

Comment: i dunno, check `DocumentSnapshot` official documentation

Answer (score 1):

I found a plugin called fake_cloud_firestore. With that, I can pass the test with fake data

Comment: also you should read this tutorial: https://blog.victoreronmosele.com/mocking-firestore-flutter